# Pointwise Convergence and Integral Equivalence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand the following question:

> Assuming $f = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, is it true that $$\int_a ^b f \text{ dx} =
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int _a ^b f_n \text{ dx}?$$

Define $$f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if } x \in [0,1/n)\\
n(nx-1) & \text{if } x \in [1/n,2/n)\\\
n & \text{if } x =2/n\\\
-n(nx-3) & \text{if } x \in (2/n,3/n)\\\
0 & \text{if } x \in [3/n,1]\
\end{array}
\right.$$
for $n = 4,5,6, \cdots$

$f_n$ is the function that connects $(0,0)$ to $(1/n,0)$ to $(2/n,n)$ to $(3/n,0)$ to $(1,0)$ with line segments. For all $b \in [0,1]$, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (b) = 0$$ since $3/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. $\text{(*)}$

So, $f_n \to f$ pointwise where $f \equiv 0$. Moreover, $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \text{dx} = 0.$$ On the other hand, for all $n$,
$$\int_0 ^{1} f_n(x) \text{dx} = (\text{area of triangle with height $n$ and base $2/n$} ) =1.$$
This shows $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0 ^1 f_n \text{ dx} \neq \int_0 ^1 f \text{ dx}.$$

**My confusion:**

My confusion arises in (*). Why do we only care about $3/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ to establish $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (b) = 0?$$ When $n \to \infty$, all three of $1/n, 2/n, $and $3/n$ tend to $0$, so that they coincide at the origin and hence provide us with “zero area.” Moreover, the peak (point) of the triangle $(2/n,n)$ would also go to $0$ as well, "flattening" the triangle. Is this all implicit by saying $3/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ or is there another reason for only mentioning this?

Comment: For any fixed $b \in (0,1]$ there is $N$ such that for $n \geqslant N$ we have $3/n \leqslant 3/N < b$ and $f_n(b) = 0$ (because the triangle base is now to the left of $b$ for such $n$). Since $f_n(b) = 0$ for all $n \geqslant N$ we can say $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(b) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement (*) is actually a reference to the last segment in the piece-wise definition of $f_n$, which is $[3/n,1]$. Since $3/n\to0$, any point $x\in(0,1]$ will be in that last segment for all $f_n$ as soon as $3/n$ "passes" $x$ on its way to the left towards zero.

In more formal language: once we pick an $x\in(0,1]$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $3/n<x$ (for example, take $N=\lceil 3/x\rceil$). This implies that for all these $n>N$, $x\in[3/n,1]$, therefore $f_n(x)=0$, and thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

That only leaves out $x=0$. But $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ from the first piece of the definition.

Of course, as you said, all three quantities $1/n$, $2/n$, and $3/n$ simultaneously approach zero. But for the argument they needed to make only the last one was important at that particular stage of the proof.